# What is the test case format in gherkin style language?

Tags: gherkin

Can we write " Given As a user I can't (cannot) login into the system" in Gherkin as a negative sentence?

Comment: This is not clear what you mean, please can you re-phrase?

Comment: Lets suppose as in gherkin style we write: Given When & Then, so in Given statement, can we write a negative step straight away like: - Given: "As a user I can't log in into the website", instead of "Given: As a user I should be able to login into the website When login credentials are wrong Then I cannot login into the system"

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely write negative phrases, but the example sentence is too broad. One alternative may be this (somewhat more realistic) scenario: "As a non-admin user, I cannot log into the admin page."
But that gives us no information about *how* to deal with this situation. Ideally when this happens, you want to state what should happen *instead of* letting the user log in.

This can be written as:

```
Given user type is not admin
When user tries to log in
Then throw error/redirect to a different page/break the whole internet and set the world aflame etc.
```